# Which is correct, in each number, or on each number or for each number?

Tags: prepositions, numbers

Which is correct, **in each number**, or **on each number** or **for each number**?
I need to ask questions mentioning that each number has a different instruction.

Any help that includes sentence examples will be so appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, Miranda. It is actually not our responsibility to supply sentence examples, but yours. If you could supply one or more context sentences, we might be better able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Context is king, all of your phrases can be grammatically correct:

> ***In** each number* from twelve to ninety-nine, the letter "t" appears at least once.
>
> When playing hopscotch, you start the game by jumping ***on** each number* in numerical order.
>
> ***For** each number* which contains a 3 or is divisible by 3, say "Fizz" instead of the number.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this is what you're getting at:

> **For** each number, there will be a different set of instructions.

But Jake is right, to get the best help, please write some example sentences to show us your needs.